# "exec format error" on docker run

Tags: executable, docker

I have a MacBook Pro running Yosemite.  On this I have Virtualbox installed with an Ubuntu system running within it.  All packages on both are reasonably up to date (within a month of current).

Within that Ubuntu VM I ran the following:

```
$ sudo bash
# apt-get install docker.io
...
# docker version
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 990021a
# docker pull centos
...
# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
...
centos              latest              88f9454e60dd        8 days ago          210 MB
# docker run -it centos /bin/bash
2015/03/12 19:59:57 exec format error
#
```

This sequence of commands is directly taken from [a popular tutorial](https://github.com/burrsutter/docker_tutorial) and a talk based on it at a recent conference.  The only difference between what I did and the tutorial is, I did not install the [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) software, rather I just installed docker directly in my pre-existing VM.

Why did this command fail, and if my configuration is to blame, what are my options on fixing it?  I prefer not to install boot2docker or other tools on the host system if possible.

Comment: Is your machine 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Host is 64, VM is 32.  I hadn't thought about that.  I guess I'll try again with a 64 bit VM.  Or maybe try to find a 32-bit image for Docker to use.